# Format a Social Security Number (SSN) as XXX-XX-XXXX from XXXXXXXXX

Tags: c#, .net, string-formatting

I am getting a social security number (SSN) from a data warehouse. While posting it to a CRM I want it to be formatted like `XXX-XX-XXXX` instead of `XXXXXXXXX`.

It's like converting a simple string with dashes at positions `4` and `7`. I am pretty new to C#, so what is the best way to do this?

Comment: BTW the ultimate C# formatting page is http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Check out the [String.Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx) method.

```
string formattedSSN = unformattedSSN.Insert(5, "-").Insert(3, "-");
```

Comment: Tricky.  It is interesting to note that the "obvious" answer of doing it like this (note my reversal of 3 and 5 compared to yours):  unformattedSSN.Insert(3,"-").Insert(5,"-"); would yield 123-4-56789 rather than 123-45-6789.  So, you are, in effect inserting dashes from back to front.

Comment: Yeah, you could do it forwards instead of backwards, but then you'd have to account for the extra dash that you inserted.

Comment: Why was this downvoted a month and a half after it was accepted?

Comment: @Gendolkari This is a fine example of a situation where a fluent interface is poor. As you have acknowledged, George's solution is clearer and easier to verify.

Comment: George's solution fails when the SSN is stored as a string, which is specified in the question.

Comment: @mdelvecchio Never mind correctness -- being easier to read is clearly a greater virtue than actually solving the problem.

Comment: @Casey no, SO is all about accuracy in answers. that's why we're here. as for this problem, the SSN is a string, thus George's answer won't work since its for a numeric data type. change the question if you like, but numeric is a different problem than string.

Comment: @mdelvecchio I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure Casey was being sarcastic and agreeing with you.

Comment: @GendoIkari That was, indeed, what I meant.

Comment: ah..missed it for some reason last nite, sorry.  /s tag helps tho!

Comment: @Ch'nycos Then this would throw a runtime error. There are plenty of ways to avoid this; but I think it's outside the scope of the question.

Answer (score 56):

For a simple, short, and self commenting solution, try:

```
String.Format("{0:000-00-0000}", 123456789)
```

`123456789` representing your SSN variable.

Comment: You have an extra # in the middle. Other than that, +1 because it's much more elegant than my solution.

Comment: Close, but you need "{0:000-00-0000}" instead of '#' to allow for leading zeroes (or "{0:00#-##-####}" etc.).

Comment: You are assuming that the data is coming in a numeric form.  I am not sure how SSN data is typically kept but I would have expected a 9 character string rather than a numerical value given the specification for the first 3 chars includes leading zeroes.  If the former then you would need to add in a string->numeric conversion (or is there an implicit one?).

Comment: yeah this fails -- the question specifies the SSN value is a string, and this solution will not work on a string.

Comment: This isn't a good solution - SSNs should never be stored as a number because they can start with a 0. This only works for formatting a number.  The accepted answer is the right answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
string ssn = "123456789";

string formattedSSN = string.Join("-", 
                                  ssn.Substring(0,3), 
                                  ssn.Substring(3,2), 
                                  ssn.Substring(5,4));
```

@George's option is probably cleaner if the SSN is stored as a numeric rather than as a string.

start indexes corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case this helps someone, here is a method I created to mask and format a SSN:

**USAGE:**

```
string ssn = "123456789";
string masked = MaskSsn(ssn); // returns xxx-xx-6789
```

**CODE:**

```
public static string MaskSsn(string ssn, int digitsToShow = 4, char maskCharacter = 'x')
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ssn)) return String.Empty;

    const int ssnLength = 9;
    const string separator = "-";
    int maskLength = ssnLength - digitsToShow;

    // truncate and convert to number
    int output = Int32.Parse(ssn.Replace(separator, String.Empty).Substring(maskLength, digitsToShow));

    string format = String.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < maskLength; i++) format += maskCharacter;
    for (int i = 0; i < digitsToShow; i++) format += "0";

    format = format.Insert(3, separator).Insert(6, separator);
    format = "{0:" + format + "}";

    return String.Format(format, output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without data validation and assuming that you only get 9 character string, I would go with something like this -

```
return s.Substring(0, 3) + "-" + s.Substring(3, 2) + "-" + s.Substring(5, 4);
```

But...I am also pretty new...so GendoIkari's answer is soo much better.

Answer (score 0):

Above answer might be raise exception when string not fixed length.

In my case I used following way SSN formating and its working.

```
string SSN = "56245789";
if (SSN.Length > 3 && SSN <= 5)
      SSN = SSN.Insert(3, "-");
else if (SSN.Length > 5)
      SSN = SSN.Insert(5, "-").Insert(3, "-");
```

Hence SSN will get 562-45-789.

Answer (score 0):

George Johnston's answer is a great answer and the cleanest. Just needs a bit extra work in case there are one or two leading 0's, and this sample assumes your starting point is an SSN in a String format. Check this out:

```
var socialInString = "003456789";
var formattedSSN = Convert.ToInt32(socialInString).ToString("###-##-####").PadLeft(11, '0');
```