# Convert card numbers to XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-0000 Format

Tags: c#, string.format

I have a 16 character string that comes through something like this:

```
1234567891234567
```

I need to be able to format the string as it would appear in a system i.e

```
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-4567
```

**NOTE** that the 4567 digits shown above relate to the last four digits of the card number.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128263/format-a-social-security-number-ssn-as-xxx-xx-xxxx-from-xxxxxxxxx) question helps format the string to something like `1234-5678-9123-4567`

But it does not help with the format required above.

While looking for answers I also came across the following solution:

```
    string[] subStrings = Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Select(n => cardNumber.Substring(n * 4, 4)).ToArray();
    string result = String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}", subStrings);
```

but again this will only output the string as something like `1234-5678-9123-4567`

I seem to have reached part of the solution, but cant format the rest.

Comment: I don't understand. In your example should it show as `XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-4567`?

Comment: @Equalsk Hi i just updated the question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your string credit card number will always be 16 digits, then you can do something like:

```
string str = "1234567891234567";    
string output = "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-" + str.Substring(str.Length - 4);
```

Comment: Great answer and it only involves one line of code, very efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You could reassign the array values.

```
subStrings[0] = subStrings[1] = subStrings[2] = "XXXX"
```

Answer (score 1):

Keeping your original code, you could just do:

```
string[] subStrings = Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Select(n => cardNumber.Substring(n * 4, 4)).ToArray();
string result = String.Format("XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-{0}", subStrings[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a char[] from your string then you can group your char[] into chunks of char[4] then you can simply join your char[4] into dashed string. Can you try the code below;

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string source = "1234567891234567";
        int chunkSize = 4;

        List<string> chunks = (from i in source.ToCharArray().Select((value, index) => new { Value = value, Index = index })
                                  group i.Value by i.Index / chunkSize into g
                                  select g).Select(x => string.Join("",x)).ToList();


        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("-",chunks));
        Console.WriteLine("XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-"+chunks.Last());
        Console.WriteLine(chunks.First()+"-XXXX-XXXX-"+chunks.Last());
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.
PS: You can pick any nth index of your chunk to mask or show.